column "orderentit.dt_start_date" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
I see many related queries, but its not help me.
I have a query: (This is part of a large query where the error is localized)
select new com.example.docflow.orders.vo.OrderCountVo(case when o.startDate > :currentDate then 'FUTURE' else 'ACTIVE' end) 
from OrderEntity o 
group by case when o.startDate > :currentDate then 'FUTURE' else 'ACTIVE' end

Setting the parameter:
query.setParameter(CURRENT_DATE_PARAM_NAME, new Date(), TemporalType.TIMESTAMP);

new Date() from package java.util.Date.
o.startDate in Entity class:
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name = "dt_start_date")
private Date startDate;

Hibernate log:

Query from log:
select 
  case when orderentit0_.dt_start_date > ? then 'FUTURE' else 'ACTIVE' end as col_0_0_ 
from 
  ORD_ORDER orderentit0_ 
group by 
  case when orderentit0_.dt_start_date > ? then 'FUTURE' else 'ACTIVE' end

Im debug hibernate binder and get real param that set - "2024-04-05 19:02:57.757+04".
That's interesting if I hardcode this param, the query will work!!!

I know that aggregating or adding a field to a group by will help, but I'm interested in finding out why the expression above doesn't work with parameters, but it works with hardcode date.
Also, when I was debugging the query, I got this exception when the date in select and group by are different, even by 1 millisecond. But as mentioned above, I set the date in 1 place, I also checked these dates for equality in the hibernate source code and there they are equal.

Current version postgresql is 11 and hibernate is 5.2.18. i try increase postgres and hibernate version.
Explain to me the reason for this behavior, thank you in advance.
debug hibernate, see logs hibernate, logs postgres, read related topics
